# Python: Creating text files from code

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to create a text file from my code. This is what I have so far:

```
with open ("text.txt", "wt") as out_file:
    for i in range (0,len(words)):
         out_file.write(words[i])
         out_file.write" "

with open ("numberpositions.txt", "wt") as out_file:
   for j in range (0,len(numberpositions)):
        print (numberpositions)
        out_file.write(str(numberpositions[j])
        out_file.write(" ")
```

This last part `out_file.write(" ")` keeps producing a syntax error. I don't understand how this is an error and how to rectify this error. Any ideas?

Comment: `out_file.write(str(numberpositions[j])` is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know what that comment is about sorry (EDIT: you've now deleted it) or how it relates to the issue in the question. You will find this error quite frequently where the syntax error is reported on a line that, logically, has nothing wrong with it because `out_file.write(str(numberpositions[j])` a valid statement that might be split over multiple lines... until it gets to `out_file.write(" ")`.